# qt signals cause segmentation fault on connect

Tags: c++, qt, layout, signals, signals-slots

I made a widget that behaves as a window and when a button is pressed it simply emits a signal:

```
signals:
    void SaveTask( void );
```

in my mainwindow.cpp I define (in the constructor):

```
connect( taskWindow, SIGNAL(SaveTask()), task_view, SLOT(UpdateFromTasks()) );
```

taskWindow = pointer to window where this signal emits.
task_view = pointer to treewidget in mainwindow with a slot.

It is designed so that when you save a task it is displayed in the treeview.

unfortunately when I try to run the program it causes a segfault on the connect line, when I remove it the program just runs fine (apart from this functionality ofcourse). It does compile and all elements are initialized and useable. I simply don't see how this can fail.

Comment: Can you show the constructor code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like maybe you are doing the connection before you have initalized the taskWindow or task_view and are using uninitialized pointers.

Also you could try this signature (which should be the same thing, but just for good measure)

```
signals:
    void SaveTask();
```

Comment: Null pointers should result in `connect` returning `false` according to the source. Uninitialized pointers could do just about anything though.

Comment: Thanks. Just switched out that word

Comment: That's the problem, everything's initialized. And other signals work. Just the one I try to emit doesn't (at runtime it just segfaults on the connect)

Comment: Fixed it, apparently I called the connect function before initialisation.

My code is a mess!

Comment: Ya sometimes even when you swear you have taken all the steps, you can overlook some order of operations. Always helps to have another eye look at it!

Comment: Certainly. Had to take a break to see it. I was just editing the OP when it hit me: ConnectUI(); happened before the initialisation...