# No such slot when connecting widget signal with parent widget slot

Tags: qt, qwidget, qt-signals, qt-connection

I have the following classes:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QStringList pluginsToStart, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

// some other stuff

public slots:
    void on_timeDataChanged(logging::TimeValueVector<bool>& aData);
    void on_importStarted();
}
```

and

```
class DataImporterWidget : public PluginWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit DataImporterWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~DataImporterWidget();

    void initConnections(QMap<QString, PluginWidget*> pluginWidgetMap);
```

in the method initConnections, I want the widget to init the signal-slot connections like so:

```
void DataImporterWidget::initConnections(QMap<QString, PluginWidget*> pluginWidgetMap)
{
    for(Importer* importer : this->getImporterMap().values())
    {
        connect(importer, SIGNAL(signal_timeDataChanged(logging::TimeValueVector<bool>&)),
            parentWidget(), SLOT(on_timeDataChanged(logging::TimeValueVector<bool>&)));
    }

    connect(this, SIGNAL(signal_importStarted()), parentWidget(), SLOT(on_importStarted()));
}
```

Importer is a QGroupBox and a base class for derived sub classes specifying concrete data importer types.
It works like so: If I press a button, an DataImporterWidget is created and added to a QMdiArea as a QMdiSubWindow. When creating the DataImporterWidget I call the initConnections() method which sets up the signal-slot connections.

Now, when I run the program, I get the following message:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot 
QMdiSubWindow::on_timeDataChanged(logging::TimeValueVector<bool>&) in src/dataimporter/DataImporterWidget.cpp:81
QObject::connect: No such slot QMdiSubWindow::on_importStarted() in src/dataimporter/DataImporterWidget.cpp:85
QObject::connect:  (sender name:   'DataImporterWidget')
```

I do not understand why I get it because the slot is there. Even if I cast the parentWidget to the MainWindow, I get the same error.

PluginWidget is just a base class deriving from QWidget that holds some common functionality for my used plugins. 
I put Q_OBJECT on each base and derived class but still get this error. However, if I set up the connections in the MainWindow, it works just fine, but I wonder why the above solution won't work.

Comment: `parentWidget` doesn't seem to be of type `MainWindow`.

Comment: This would be a good time to start using the [new signal slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) introduced in Qt 5; this way you'll get a clearer error at compile time.

Comment: If I use the new signal slot syntax, my program crashes with a segmentation fault in the slot method of the MainWindow class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. The reason is, that the MainWidget class holds a QMdiArea where I add my PluginWidgets. So, when I create the PluginWidget, I set the MainWidget as its parent, but as soon as I add it to the QMdiArea, it also becomes a child of QMdiSubWindow. The parentWidget was never null but it was the wrong one ...

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the connection from child object, instead create it from parent object code after creating the child object.
This way you won't need to cast any type.

Answer (score 0):

You did not shown a huge chunk of important code (like creating `DataImporterWidget`, setting `MainWindow` as its parent, the place where you call `initConnections`...). However, you said

> If I use the new signal slot syntax, my program crashes with a
>   segmentation fault...

If it crashes, than you have to find a reason why. Using old signal-slot connect syntax does not cure the disease, it just delay its manifestation. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019929/qt-signals-cause-segmentation-fault-on-connect), the reason why you get a segfault can be `parentWidget() == nullptr` or `parent` is not initialized yet.

My advice, check your code, and make user the parent of `DataImporterWidget` is created and specified before your call `initConnections()`.